# Phase Difference between Electric and Magnetic Field in EM waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, maxwell-equations

Is it possible to get a phase difference between an Electric Field ($E$) and a Magnetic Field ($M$) in an electromagnetic wave and why are they in phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Classical electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism) developed in order to fit the observations and data and be predictive of new setups.

[Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) gave the final mathematical model that fits all observations of light and is accurately predictive of any new interactions with matter. In vacuum, these equations lead to solutions where light is an electromagnetic wave with electric and magnetic fields in phase.

One cannot introduce a phase difference between electric and magnetic fields in the theory,and still fit the data in vacuum ( or where matter can be ignored in the solutions of the equations), so the answer is no,not in vacuum.  It is possible mathematically but the theory would have no connection with the measurements and observations. Within and with matter this is a different story, and has to be examined for the given problem. For example see the answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258450/a-formula-for-the-phase-difference-between-the-electric-and-magnetic-wave-oscill) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/628062/why-are-the-electric-and-magnetic-fields-in-phase-in-em-waves).

Comment: This is not correct.In any material which has conductance the electric and magnetic fields have a phase difference.

Comment: Can you please give a  link for your assertion? Do you mean the electric and magnetic fields of the beam of light, or of the material?

Comment: Also the relationship between $E$ and $B$ is irrelevant.What is important is the relationship between $E$ and $H$.Page 7 of this:https://hep.physics.illinois.edu/home/serrede/P436/Lecture_Notes/P436_Lect_07.pdf.

Comment: @Cerise Thanks for the comments, I have edited to clarify.

Comment: @Cerise could you provide the mathematical expression for the phase difference in an arbitrary material if possible?

Comment: @ParthSareen page 7 of the link.

Comment: @Cerise Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The relationship between $E_i$ and $H_j$ is given by the impedance $Z = \sqrt{\epsilon/\mu}.$ It can have an imaginary part, introducing a phase $\arg(Z)$. For example in the Debye model, you have $\epsilon \sim 1 + \alpha/(1 + i \omega \tau) $. More generally, the conductivity of a medium leads to losses, i.e. $\Im(k) < 0$. You effectively get an imaginary speed of light $c^* = \sqrt{\mu \epsilon}$ with $\Im{\epsilon} \sim$ -conductivity, leading to an imaginary impedance $Z = \omega \mu /k$. The imaginary part of $k$ represents the attenuation of the wave as it propagates through a medium. This attenuation is due to the absorption of energy by the medium. You don't have this in free space, where $c^* = c$ and $Z = \sqrt{\epsilon_0 / \mu_0}$.